# How to delete rows given conditions in R?

Tags: r

So I know how to delete rows based off one column condition.  How do I do it for multiple conditions?

Date Frame = "olddata"

```
Letter Number Color
X 1 Blue
Y 3 Red
Z 5 Yellow
D 1 Red
F 1 Yellow
X 2 Green
```

For example, to delete rows with the Letter X in it, and rows with color green, you can do:

```
newdata <- subset(olddata, olddata$Letter != "X" & olddata$Color != "Green")
```

Now how do I delete Rows that have the letter F and is Yellow, i.e. both criteria must be met.

Thanks!

Comment: Combine your criteria and then negate it - `olddata[!(olddata$Letter == "F" & olddata$Color == "Yellow"),]`

Comment: already saw that question and the formula didn't work for me:

Comment: tried d<-d[!(d$A=="B" & d$E==0),] and it didn't remove any rows for whatever reason.  stared at it for like an hour and didn't see anything wrong with syntax.  subset worked but it didn't allow me to give 2 criteria, only 1

Comment: Are you sure, because the answer there is identical in logic to my comment above, and I can confirm it works with your current data.

Comment: `subset` will allow multiple criteria for sure - `subset(mtcars, cyl == 4 & mpg > 30)` for a reproducible example.

Comment: Look carefully. The difference between the answer below and the one given by @thelatemail is in parentheses. thelatemail correctly negates the entire condition, while the answer below does it to the first term only.

Comment: in this: subset(mtcars, cyl == 4 & mpg > 30) I'm pretty sure that removes any row that has either cyl = 4 and or mpg >30.  It does not remove just the rows that are BOTH cyl = 4 and mpg >30.  At least that what happens when I used that formula

Comment: @user6472523 - *"I'm pretty sure that removes any row that has either cyl = 4 and or mpg >30"* - actually it *keeps* any row that has `cyl==4` **and** `mpg>30`. You'd use `subset(mtcars, !(mtcars$cyl == 4 & mtcars$mpg > 30))` if you wanted to remove the rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
newdata <- olddata[!(olddata$Letter == "F" & olddata$Color == "Yellow"),]
```

Comment: That would remove both rows 3 and 6.  It's just like my old formula.  I want to remove just row 6.

Comment: If you're going to use `subset`, no need for `olddata$` again each time.

Comment: @thelatemail, that's good to know. I prefer base R and I assumed subset basically functioned the same way, changing my answer to base R.

Comment: No problems. `subset` is base R by the way, just a 'non-standard evaluation' function that R provides. Also, I think you need to negate your whole selection - at the moment you're keeping "F"/"Yellow" rows rather than deleting them.

Comment: lol... yes ... yes I am.

Comment: Just to continue to be a nuisance - `!olddata$Letter == "F" & olddata$Color == "Yellow"` is not the same as `!(olddata$Letter == "F" & olddata$Color == "Yellow")` - check each result in the console (I didn't downvote btw).

Comment: I feel like I'm in a slap stick routine. lol.

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
library(dplyr)

olddata %>%
filter(olddata, Letter!="F" & Color!="Yellow")
```

Comment: This doesn't give the right result.

Comment: Do you mean `require(dplyr); df %>% filter(!(Letter == "F" & Color == "Yellow"));`?